# Performance issue, drawing app on iOS with OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, performance, opengl-es

I’m currently developing a drawing app on iOS, with OpenGL ES 2.0 (I begin using it). I would like to reproduce textured brushes on my app. For that, I decided to use shaders (best choice?). At this stage, I have my textured brushes, but unfortunately, I also have some performance problems after few seconds…

Here is an overview of my app process:

1. I receive about 140 points each second.
2. Each time, on the draw function, I browse all of my points (points of contained on the Stroke class, which is contained on the layer) and I redraw it.

Code:

```
for (int strokeId = 0; strokeId < layer->strokesList.size(); strokeId++) {
    Stroke* stroke = layer->strokesList.at(strokeId);

    […]

    glVertexAttribPointer(mainProgram.positionSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, stroke->vertices.Position);
    glVertexAttribPointer(mainProgram.colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, stroke->vertices.Color);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, (int)(stroke->nbVertices));

    […]
}
```

I am opened to any suggestion to improve this drawing method, thank you!